# How to get data from xml file using groovy?

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

Following groovy script is not working as expected.

```
def xml="<Collection><CustomerQuote><ID>99988877766</ID><TypeCode>2059</TypeCode><ApprovalStatusCode>4</ApprovalStatusCode></CustomerQuote><CustomerQuote><ID>99988877755</ID><TypeCode>2059</TypeCode><ApprovalStatusCode>4</ApprovalStatusCode></CustomerQuote></Collection>"
    
 def completeXml= new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml);
 def IDs = completeXml.Collection.CustomerQuote.findAll{node-> node.name() == 'ID' }*.text();
```

I am trying to copy all the ID value in xml in the IDs

`Output`

`IDs[]`

`Expected Output`

`IDs[99988877766,99988877755]`

I am not sure what i am doing wrong here.

Can anyone guide.

Thank you
Regards
Prat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root node has to be omitted when using `XmlSlurper`, and you don't need to use `findAll` for this.

```
def xml="<Collection><CustomerQuote><ID>99988877766</ID><TypeCode>2059</TypeCode><ApprovalStatusCode>4</ApprovalStatusCode></CustomerQuote><CustomerQuote><ID>99988877755</ID><TypeCode>2059</TypeCode><ApprovalStatusCode>4</ApprovalStatusCode></CustomerQuote></Collection>"
    
def completeXml= new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml);
def IDs = completeXml.CustomerQuote.ID*.text();
```

Will output:

```
[
  "99988877766",
  "99988877755"
]
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJy1kE8LgkAQxe9-isWTdtiNyH80CqEXj6GHrqITBKu7rLtl375NKCyiW-8085jHj3kdnsjU89SFXHCOrT6LIYPcjFr0qA5GaMygLLIkSeI4jqIoDIHZHeqbxFx0mG3WQQLstcJeSiUuDa90o804e1tgX1xgH5gf1CD4G5UtHncdYuV0tpRW9JKjxqMthwx4JXaouFESledT2agRa5y0Z8vzd3OiLEaSLnP0jUTLYkX1I2LvnRn01B0JVIHZ)